# How to show context menu on a ListBoxItem template on a grid when right-clicking outside the contents of it?

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu, datatemplate

Hello,

I have a `ListBox.ItemTemplate` (containing obviously a `DataTemplate`) containing a `Grid` which itself contains a `Label`.

The `Grid` has a `Grid.ContextMenu`. The issue is that the `ContextMenu` only shows when I right click on the **`Label`**. Not outside.

Here is an image to show the problem if you didn't understand (But I am sure you did ;) !)

[image]

Here is the code :

```xml
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <Grid Margin="0,0,0,1">
         <Grid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
               <MenuItem CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference window}, Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand}" Header="Supprimer">
                  <MenuItem.Icon>
                     <Image Source="/SchoolTools.Teacher;component/Images/DeleteIcon.png" />
                  </MenuItem.Icon>
               </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
         </Grid.ContextMenu>
         <Label Content="{Binding ClassYear}" Padding="0" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
      </Grid>
   </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the label's HorizontalAlignment to Stretch so that it fills the entire grid cell.

Comment: Oh, dumb me, it works now, thanks ! (I have also added `HorizontalContentAlignement="Center"` )